# what should i change my sql statement so that i can arrive with this table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i am stuck with this problem i have tables

Complaints:

[Complaint table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDEdE.jpg)

User:

[User table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDmdj.jpg)

and i want to extract complaints of the users that are in the specific province

example: if i want to extract the complaints of the province of ILOCOS my table would look like this

```
complaint_id | user_id | complaint_title| complaint_category | complaint_desc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17           | 2       | 2              | Accidents          | qwe123
```

ive arrived with this sql statement :

```
SELECT DISTINCT complaint.complaint_id, complaint.user_id,
      complaint.complaint_title,complaint.complaint_desc                         
FROM complaint LEFT JOIN
     user
     ON user.province = 'ILOCOS' LEFT JOIN
     complaint_media
     ON complaint.complaint_id = complaint_media.complaint_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join complaint table with user table on user_id column otherwise it will be a cartesian join.

```
select distinct complaint.complaint_id,   -- check if you really need "DISTINCT"
    complaint.user_id,
    complaint.complaint_title,
    complaint.complaint_desc,
    . . .
from complaint
join user
    on complaint.user_id = user.user_id     -- here
        and user.province = 'ILOCOS'
join complaint_media
    on complaint.complaint_id = complaint_media.complaint_id
```

Comment: owhh it doesnt need distinct and it didnt get what i want, it still displays all of the complaints :( not the complaints of the province of ILOCOS

Comment: @JoshuaLee - That's becase you are using left join. You want an inner join then. Updated the answer.

Comment: @JoshuaLee - You don't need to write `inner` for an `inner join`. Just `join` is enough. It's by default inner only.

Comment: thank you so much it works now, i am really not good with joining tables phew :D you're a life saver i wont resort now with the brute force method that i have in mind haha

Comment: owhh i didnt know hahaha noted